# adding new attributes from decorator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass parameters between my father and template driver of a directive, but this appears to be malfunctioning

the method in the controller is

```
vm.activoHora = function(eventos, hora, dia) {

  var a = eventos;
  var b = hora;
  var c = moment(dia).format('MM/DD/YYYY');


  angular.forEach(eventos, function(value, key) {

    var fechaEv = moment(value.startsAt).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    if (fechaEv === c)
      var horaEv = moment(value.startsAt).format('HH:mm');

    if (horaEv === b)
      $scope.valor = true;
    return $scope.valor;
  });

  return ({
    ' btn-danger disabled': $scope.valor
  });

}
```

this should evaluate the day and return an object css to disable the drawer,`evento` used to communicate with the template

```
<mwl-calendar 
          evento="vm.activohora(event,hora,dia)" 
          events="vm.events" 
   ...........            
  </mwl-calendar>
```

and the template evaluated with ng-class

```
 <li   class="list-group-item col-md-12 " ng-class="vm.evento(vm.view.events,h_m,day)" ng-repeat="h_m in [] | tiempoTabla:8:16:15" style="padding: 1px !important">
      <p  class="hora text-center" style=" margin: inherit" ng-click="vm.clic(day.date,h_m)">{{h_m}}</p>
 </li>
```

Here is the code where the problem occurred  http://plnkr.co/edit/XihZabCHjLHtPiCQnbUi?p=preview

Comment: It is not clear what is the question. Yes, you have to use $$isolateBindings to decorate directive scope bindings.

Comment: I can not pass parameters between "myweek.html" parent template and controller

Comment: Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), at plunker or elsewhere. You've got several detached snippets of code in your question which give no opportunity to guess what is wrong.

Comment: edit my question to give a greater understanding and also an example plunk agrege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vm.activohora` is being called, while the actual function is `vm.activoHora`.

`$scope` is being used, while it wasn't injected into controller.

`eventos, hora, dia` parameters aren't defined on the scope.

The problems require careful debugging and aren't related to the subject. Attribute binding is fine, though one-way binding (`@`) should be used instead for the object that is returned by the function.

Comment: I realized if those mistakes and change, and let the functions without parameters and return the CSS for all cells s desabiliten and see if it works well, but still does not work, when debugging, I realize that falls within function but does nothing  http://embed.plnkr.co/XihZabCHjLHtPiCQnbUi/preview

Comment: Everything in in the console. You've got infinite digest. Exactly because you're using two-way = binding on function return instead of one-way.

Comment: the truth I'm just starting to use the guidelines and have little understanding of it, but changed to "@" and does not work

Comment: You need also `evento="{{ vm.activoHora() }}" `. And the difference is more than just syntactic, = is reserved especially for binding to scope properties.

Comment: Like it was said above, replace two-way binding with one-way. http://plnkr.co/edit/at81Cvnj4ZhLscQMW8Xa?p=preview I would suggest to start with similar but much more simple setup and figure out what exactly is going on there. Hacking a complex directive just like that can be painful.

Comment: How else can I use ?, the idea is to send the current time of ng-repeat to evaluate a function and return the css to disable the drawer

Comment: I'm not sure, the code is too complex to sort it out and suggest something relevant. Most probably the recipe is the same as usually in such cases. Wrap a 3rd-party directive with your own. Make your nested directives talk to parent one with `require`d controllers or events. Save decoration for the cases where it is certainly a good option.

Comment: I'm doing a test, create an alert management and console me this print parameter received, and all are undefined http://embed.plnkr.co/XihZabCHjLHtPiCQnbUi/preview

Comment: You're still doing evento="vm.activoHora()", while the proper usage is evento="{{ vm.activoHora() }}". I have to recommend to check the manual on basics before jumping into something that complex. The parts on [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) are essential.

Comment: I'm not working with vm.activoHora (), now I'm testing the passage of the direct parameters with a new policy of type E

Comment: I guess you will have to split your tasks into several questions. It is unlikely that somebody can help to figure out this amount of varying code at once.